# Получить значение option title из datalist. jQuery, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datalist

надо передать в `value input id="id_clients-name"` по нажатию на `option` в `datalist` значение `title` (использую его как поле hidden, может есть лучше варианты?). Как это сделать?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ajax_phone_{{ widget.name }}').on('change', function() {
    $('#id_clients-name').val($('#' + $(this).attr('list')).find('option[title="' + $(this).title() + '"]').text());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="clients-name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="150" id="id_clients-name">

<input id="ajax_phone_clients-phone" list="clients-phone" name="clients-phone" value="+7" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите название...">

<datalist id="clients-phone">
        <option value="32" title="Egor">+79121234567</option>
        <option value="31" title="eg">+79216840525</option>
        <option value="28" title="SomeText">+79211234567</option>
        </datalist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На stackoverflow множество вариантов есть, один из них:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ajax_phone_clients-phone').on('input',function() {
      var opt = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
      $('#id_clients-name').val(opt.length ? opt.attr('title') : 'Пользователь не выбран') 
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="clients-name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="150" id="id_clients-name">

<input id="ajax_phone_clients-phone" list="clients-phone" name="clients-phone" value="+7" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите название...">

<datalist id="clients-phone">
        <option value="32" title="Egor">+79121234567</option>
        <option value="31" title="eg">+79216840525</option>
        <option value="28" title="SomeText">+79211234567</option>
        </datalist>
```